# Generating & Modifying PDF in JS

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have found a couple of libraries that allow to generate/edit/read PDFs in javascript like jsPDF, Mozzila's pdf.js.
And these were present before the advent of ES6 or HTML5. So no modern technologies were present.

I want to understand from a JS perspective how these libraries have achieved to do this? As far as I understand PDF file/format/container is Proprietary having Open SDKs for different languages which are then used by Softwares, like the one MS Word may use for converting DOC to PDF.

An SDK for JS seems unlikely since the whole code runs on the client side and does not support interfacing with binaries of other languages. So how would one actually create a pdf file in JS which runs in the browsers' js compiler. Looking at the libraries it seems that is what they have done.

Answer (score 0):

Julien Viereck has a great youtube video online explaining how pdf.js works internally.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iv15UY-4Fg8

You can also browse the PDF.js codebase to learn more (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently special about a PDF file that prevents it from being created by anything that can write text and binary to a file. The object definitions can become quite complex but it's still just a matter of conforming to the specification.

It's all laid out in the [PDF Reference](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwibj6LS0PHSAhWByLwKHd94CsYQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adobe.com%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2FAdobe%2Fen%2Fdevnet%2Facrobat%2Fpdfs%2Fpdf_reference_1-7.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHy7q3uO_QDuDeHLydS12RpbpRRYg).